# Using contains function in Azure Data Factory Dataflow expression builder

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am using Azure Data Factory in which a data flow is used, I want to split my file in to two based on a condition. I am attaching an image with 2 lines, the first one is working but I want to use more programatic approach to achieve the same output:

[image]

I have a column named `indicator` inside my dataset, I want to use `contains` functionality to split the data, basically having 1 file where a string value inside `indicator` column has substring `Weekly` or does not.

Similar to what I would use in pandas:

```
df1 = df[df.indicator.str.contains('Weekly')]
df2 = df[~df.indicator.str.contains('Weekly')]
```

[image]

Comment: Is 'weekly' occurs only at start of your values?

Comment: Yes, but I am looking for an answer where it can appear anywhere in the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below expression as well in the Conditional split.

`contains()` expects an array. So first split the column content to create the array and give this to contains function.

```
contains(split(indicator, ' '),#item=='weekly')
```

This is my sample data.

[image]

**Conditional split:**

[image]

**Weekly data in the output:**

[image]

**Remaining data:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this worked, however in my case I had to use upper case `Weekly`, I am not sure why is that because according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/contains-operator) `contains` is not case-sensitive, do you know why is that?

Comment: In that case you can try like this `contains(split(lower(indicator), ' '),#item=='weekly')` or upper before contains.

Comment: Thanks, but shouldn't `contains` ignore the case per default?

Comment: I think [This documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/contains-operator) is related kustos not ADF dataflow and as per my repro contains is not case sensitive in Data flow expression.

Comment: Also, in Data flow expression it expects array not string.

Comment: @JonasPalačionis the '==' condition is case sensitive. You might want to try '<=>' (case insensitive version) instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the existing of a value inside of a string scalar column, use instr().

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-expressions-usage#instr